# Получить текст в <title>*</title>

Tags: php

Мне нужно получить текст из тега

```
<title>этот текст нужно получить</title>
```

Я делаю так:

```
preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $html, $match);
```

Но иногда *title* может быть таким

```
<title data-random>этот текст нужно получить</title>
```

Мне нужно нечто такое:

```
"/<title тут_любые_символы>(.*)<\/title>/i"
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: тебе нужен либо SimpleXML  либо DOMDocument, а не это извращение

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать библиотеку phpQuery https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/

Работает точно так же как JQuery